# Showing an image from an array of images - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, image

I have a large image which is shown on my homepage, and when the user clicks the "next_img" button the large image on the homepage should change to the next image in the array.

However, the next arrow when clicked does nothing, and the main image on the homepage does not change.

I need to do this in javascript.

In the HTML:

```
<!--Main Content of the page -->

<div id="splash">
<img src="images/img/Splash_image1.jpg" alt="" id="mainImg">

</div> 

<div id="imglist">
<a href="javascript:nextImage('mainImg')"><img src="images/next_img.png" alt=""></a>
```

And then in the javascript file:

```
var imgArray = new Array();

imgArray[0] = new Image();
imgArray[0].src = 'images/img/Splash_image1.jpg';

imgArray[1] = new Image();
imgArray[1].src = 'images/img/Splash_image2.jpg';

imgArray[2] = new Image();
imgArray[2].src = 'images/img/Splash_image3.jpg';

imgArray[3] = new Image();
imgArray[3].src = 'images/img/Splash_image4.jpg';

imgArray[4] = new Image();
imgArray[4].src = 'images/img/Splash_image5.jpg';

imgArray[5] = new Image();
imgArray[5].src = 'images/img/Splash_image6.jpg';

/*------------------------------------*/

function nextImage(element)
{
    var img = document.getElementById(element);

    for(var i = 0;i<imgArray.length;i++)
    {
        if(imgArray[i] == img)
        {
            if(i == imgArray.length)
            {
                var j = 0;
                document.getElementById(element).src = imgArray[j].src;
                break;
            }
            else
            var j = i + 1;
            document.getElementById(element).src = imgArray[j].src;
            break;
        }
    }   
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just as Diodeus said, you're comparing an `Image` to a `HTMLDomObject`. Instead compare their `.src` attribute:

```
var imgArray = new Array();

imgArray[0] = new Image();
imgArray[0].src = 'images/img/Splash_image1.jpg';

imgArray[1] = new Image();
imgArray[1].src = 'images/img/Splash_image2.jpg';

/* ... more images ... */

imgArray[5] = new Image();
imgArray[5].src = 'images/img/Splash_image6.jpg';

/*------------------------------------*/

function nextImage(element)
{
    var img = document.getElementById(element);

    for(var i = 0; i < imgArray.length;i++)
    {
        if(imgArray[i].src == img.src) // << check this
        {
            if(i === imgArray.length){
                document.getElementById(element).src = imgArray[0].src;
                break;
            }
            document.getElementById(element).src = imgArray[i+1].src;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nuktu: You're welcome. Please keep in mind: even if `imgArray[0] = Image()` and `img = document.getElementById(#myimage)` are treated as `HTMLImageElement`, they won't be the same even if they are equal (same attributes) as they're different object _instances_.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a somewhat cleaner way of implementing this.  This makes the following changes:

1. The code is DRYed up a bit to remove redundant and repeated code and strings.
2. The code is made more generic/reusable.
3. We make the cache into an object so it has a self-contained interface and there are fewer globals.
4. We compare `.src` attributes instead of DOM elements to make it work properly.

Code:

```
function imageCache(base, firstNum, lastNum) {
    this.cache = [];
    var img;
    for (var i = firstNum; i <= lastnum; i++) {
        img = new Image();
        img.src = base + i + ".jpg";
        this.cache.push(img);
    }
}

imageCache.prototype.nextImage(id) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    var targetSrc = element.src;
    var cache = this.cache;
    for (var i = 0; i < cache.length; i++) {
        if (cache[i].src) === targetSrc) {
            i++;
            if (i >= cache.length) {
                i = 0;
            }
            element.src = cache[i].src;
            return;
        }
    }
}

// sample usage

var myCache = new imageCache('images/img/Splash_image', 1, 6);
myCache.nextImage("foo");
```

Some advantages of this more object oriented and DRYed approach:

1. You can add more images by just creating the images in the numeric sequences and changing one numeric value in the constructor rather than copying lots more lines of array declarations.
2. You can use this more than one place in your app by just creating more than one imageCache object.
3. You can change the base URL by changing one string rather than N strings.
4. The code size is smaller (because of the removal of repeated code).
5. The cache object could easily be extended to offer more capabilities such as first, last, skip, etc...
6. You could add centralize error handling in one place so if one image doesn't exist and doesn't load successfully, it's automatically removed from the cache.
7. You can reuse this in other web pages you develop by only change the arguments to the constructor and not actually changing the implementation code.

P.S. If you don't know what DRY stands for, it's "Don't Repeat Yourself" and basically means that you should never have many copies of similar looking code.  Anytime you have that, it should be reduced somehow to a loop or function or something that removes the need for lots of similarly looking copies of code.  The end result will be smaller, usually easier to maintain and often more reusable.

Comment: @Nuktu - This is what stackoverflow is good for.  Study this code.  Learn from it.  Use it.  Advance your techniques.

Answer (score 4):

Also, when checking for the last image, you must compare with `imgArray.length-1` because, for example, when array length is 2 then I will take the values 0 and 1, it won't reach the value 2, so you must compare with length-1 not with length, here is the fixed line:

```
if(i == imgArray.length-1)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple example and try to combine it with yours using some modifications. I prefer you set all the images in one array in order to make your code easier to read and shorter:

```
var myImage = document.getElementById("mainImage");

var imageArray = ["_images/image1.jpg","_images/image2.jpg","_images/image3.jpg",
  "_images/image4.jpg","_images/image5.jpg","_images/image6.jpg"];

var imageIndex = 0; 

function changeImage() {
  myImage.setAttribute("src",imageArray[imageIndex]);
  imageIndex = (imageIndex + 1) % imageArray.length;
}

setInterval(changeImage, 5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's your problem:

```
if(imgArray[i] == img)
```

You're comparing an array element to a DOM object.

Comment: ah ok, thanks! I wanted to compare the current image, to the image in the array so it would show the next image.

Comment: For that you need: imgArray[i].src == img.src

Answer (score -2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function bike()
{
var data=
["b1.jpg", "b2.jpg", "b3.jpg", "b4.jpg", "b5.jpg", "b6.jpg", "b7.jpg", "b8.jpg"];
var a;
for(a=0; a<data.length; a++)
{
document.write("<center><fieldset style='height:200px; float:left; border-radius:15px; border-width:6px;")<img src='"+data[a]+"' height='200px' width='300px'/></fieldset></center>
}
}
```